# Grails installed but not working

Tags: grails

For the past two years I have been using Groovy in SoapUI for interface testing automation. To get on new things I have planned to learn Grails. I followed installation and start up instructions mentioned on https://grails.org/wiki/quick%20start. I have made below installations on my Windows 7 32 bit machine:
1) JDK 1.8.0_45 that comes with netBeans IDE.
2) grails-3.0.1

After installation, I set my environment variable.
I decide to start with command prompt, so I started command prompt. Changed to Grails working directory and triggered below commands following instructions for first helloWorld program as mentioned on http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide:

1. grails create-app helloWorld
   This created Grails application in folder helloWorld
2. cd helloWorld
   Changed to project directory
3. grails
   Nothing happens beyond this point, cursor keeps on blinking. I expect Grails prompt to appear on triggering Grails command.

I tried running grails with JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 as well. Same Issue.

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME path variable? Please set that variable to path till bin folder excluding bin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it with the next steps:

1. **Enter to the app folder**. i.e. "cd /home/user/mygrailsjobs/hello-world"
2. Run: **`grails --stacktrace`**. Maybe it show the prompt and nothing happens, but **wait (several minutes in my case)** and will start the packages dependecies download.
3. When the download finish, you run **`grails`** command (wait several seconds) and the grails prompt appear

Answer (score 0):

***Check Java Home and Path 
***Check Grails Home and Path
in environment variables

I think this link will be helpful for create new application.
http://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html